# Composing two folds

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Suppose that (from the Lens library) I have

```
fold1 :: Fold s a
fold2 :: Fold s a
```

and I want to combine these in such a way that

```
toListOf (combine fold1 fold2) s == toListOf fold1 s ++ toListOf fold2 s
```

What is the simplest implementation of `combine`?  (It's of course possible just to manually implement it in terms of toListOf, or the like, but I suspect a more purely compositional implementation exists.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the efficient implementation is simply

```
combine f1 f2 k s = f1 k s *> f2 k s
```

though it's also possible to go via the `ReifiedFold`, though that appears to use the maybe-less-efficient `toListOf` implementation:

```
combine f1 f2 = runFold (Fold f1 <> Fold f2)
```

It took me some time to understand why the apparently asymmetric `*>` sufficed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(<>)` directly to combine the folds:

```
ghci> [1..4] ^.. (folded . filtered even <> backwards folded)
[2,4,4,3,2,1]
```

As I'm overtly assuming a `Monoid` instance rather than relying on `Fold`'s `Applicative` constraint, the types are slightly different than the ones in [your `(*>)`-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69601433/2751851). That won't matter in practice, though.